# Como recriar um sessão PHP sem deslogar o usuário

Tags: php, session, cache

É possível recriar uma `$_SESSION` em `PHP` sem deslogar o usuário?

Tenho uma área restrita onde ele pode atualizar algumas informações dele no banco de dados.

O problema é que quando ele faz o login eu crio algumas sessões para usar estas informações durante a navegação dele. Por exemplo, a foto dele (`$fotoUser = $_SESSION['fotoUser'];`), o caminho desta foto está gravado no banco de dados, e quando ele atualiza a mesma, eu atualizo o caminho no banco de dados e apago a imagem antiga na pasta para evitar acumular imagens que não estão sendo utilizadas, até aí tudo funcionando certinho.

O problema é que depois de ele atualizar a foto ou algum dado como seu nome, se ele der um <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ou mesmo <kbd>F5</kbd> para atualizar a página, a foto simplesmente fica nula, porque o caminho que esta nela é da `SESSION` criada na hora do login, então ele não pega a imagem nova. Tem como recriar a sessão sem deslogar ele, ou alguma alternativa diferente?

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples, você remove a sessão e cria outra, dentro da função de upload da imagem.

```
// Amrazena a imagem antiga para você poder deletar da pasta;
$imagemantiga = $_SESSION['fotoUser'];

// Remove a sessão $_SESSION['fotoUser']
unset($_SESSION['fotoUser']);

//Recria com um novo valor.
$_SESSION['fotoUser'] = "novafoto do usuario"
```

Faça isso para as `$_SESSION` que precisa, menos para aquela que mantem o usuário logado. Obs: não sei se carregar estes dados por `$_SESSION` seja boa ideia.